# What's the difference between xdmp:node-uri and fn:base-uri?

Tags: marklogic

It seems to me that `xdmp:node-uri` and `fn:base-uri` are the same. Is there a difference? Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`base-uri`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:base-uri) function will honor the `xml:base` attributes in the document. The [`xdmp:node-uri`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-uri) just accesses the stored location. So the latter will be a wee bit faster but if you use base attributes, inappropriate.

Comment: Also `base-uri` can be inappropriate if you want the document-uri without interference from `xml:base` attributes. For that reason I use `xdmp:node-uri` 99% of the time.